# Java - startsWith error

Tags: java, android, string, startswith

I am using method startsWith to find out, whether my string starts with desired string. Example:

```
       for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
           if(tokens[i].startsWith(ColumnName)){
                tokens[i]="";

           }
```

In tokens[i] there is a string "info REAL", in ColumnName, there is a string "info". In this comparsion, every time i get false. It is unbelivable, but even when i print it, it is like - **tokens[i]:info REAL, startsWith:info, result:false...**

I don't see any mistake here, you do? There is no TYPO in my program, I am 100% sure theese values are here correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Keep an eye on the `tokens` array. (PS: it's a bad habit to start a variable name with a capital letter: here it looks like you're using a class, although you're not.)

Comment: yes, I know it, I have just typed quick example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for spaces in the strings, its easy to overlook them in the console output.

e.g. "info REAL" vs "info  " or "info REAL" vs " info"

Comment: Thanks, it really were whitespaces, they werent visible, until I added | delimetres to console output

Comment: if this was the problem, then please mark this answer as accepted, on order for styx to gain a little more points :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's caused by whitespaces. Have you tried trimming your strings before doing that ?

Something like `tokens[i].trim().startsWith(ColumnName.trim())`